# How to get portraits of soft and plain skin by dslr, just like in studio photography?

Tags: nikon

How can I make the person in my photographs have soft and plain skin without any blemishes using my nikon dslr??

Comment: Before digital photography you would use a filter on the lens. Now there are multiple software options to do  exactly this in post processing.   do some homework  on the inter-tubes.

Comment: do you have a picture example?

Comment: Those "studio" photographs do not usually come straight out of camera looking that way, unless the model actually has "soft and plain skin without any blemishes."

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned the obvious: use makeup.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to get the soft effect using the camera only, then probably the best option is to use a filter.
The good thing about such filters is that you get the effect instantly on your photo.
But unfortunately, the bad part of it is that you don't get a perfect effect same as when it is edited through a software. besides that, you cannot revert back to the clean/original photo.

As an alternative, I suggest editing the photo after shooting so that you are able to adjust the effect with the amount that makes you satisfied.

**Photoshop** has a built in tool: Click **Filter**, then go to **Blur** and choose **Smart Blur**

Comment: Ok. Thank s. But what type of filter can I use?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the lighting. Blemishes and spot show up more in the transition from light to dark esp if that transition is harsh. Using soft lighting such as softboxes would be ideal but it sounds as though you do not have access to studio lighting so window light through netting would be good.
Having light from both sides would reduce help to so having a cheap white reflector or even large piece of white card would a good way to reflect light from the window back on the shadow side of the face.

Next use a wide aperture such as f/2.8 or wider. Use a single point of focus on your camera and focus on the eye nearest to you. This will ensure the eye is sharp but skin not on the same focal plane will be smoothed/blurred.

Finally do not use a macro lens it will bring out too much detail. Use a regular lens. If not being used hi-res you can help further by taking the photo from further away. If you are close up more fine detail is visible but form further away and then cropping you can reduce detail in the skin.

Obviously it helps if the model has good skin to start with.

Using filters can soften the image but they will soften everything - if you want to keep the eyes crisp and sharp then the above should help.

Using software to smooth is still the best option as you can then pick what blemishes to remove and keep the detail in the parts you want.

Comment: Upped for "keep the detail". Even leaving or just slightly diminishing some blemishes instead of complete removal and help keep things real. Far too many portraits go way too far IMO.